# is it possible to put app.use inside app.get

Tags: express

```
app.get('/game/', function(req, res) {
if (req.session.user) {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/game'));
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/game/index.html');        
}
else {
    res.send('not logged in ');
}
```

})

Is this legal to put app.use inside app.get like in this code? it's working as intended but I wanna know if it's legal or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using two different middleware function to sepparate two different concerns - authentification and static resources serving:

```
app.get('/game/', ensureAuthenticated, express.static(__dirname + '/game'), sendGameIndex);

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    next();        
  } else {
    res.send('not logged in ');
  }
}

function sendGameIndex(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/game/index.html');
}
```